# Has anyone ever tested best_in_place test helper methods with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, best-in-place

I found this in one demo app:

```
  it "should be able to use bip_text to update a text field" do
    @user.save!
    visit user_path(@user)
    within("#email") do
      page.should have_content("lucianapoli@gmail.com")
    end

    bip_text @user, :email, "new@email.com"

    visit user_path(@user)
    within("#email") do
      page.should have_content("new@email.com")
    end
  end
```

https://github.com/dougc84/best_in_place/blob/master/spec/integration/js_spec.rb

Seems easy.

So I copied it to my Capybara spec:

```
  before (:each) do
    @report = FactoryGirl.create(:report)
    visit report_path(@report)
  end 
  it "name", :focus do
    within("#name") do
      page.should have_content @report.name 
    end 
    bip_text @report, :name, "new name"
    visit report_path(@report)
    within("#name") do
      page.should have_content "new name"
    end 
  end
```

It's so fast I can barely see anything, but it looks like it does do something with #name field. Then page reloads and it's still old value.

Any help?

Oh btw it does work in the browser. Just can't get tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `sleep 1` before and after `bip_` helper, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the Javascript run by `bip_text` is asynchronous, but in your next line you immediately go to a different page, cutting off that Javascript from ever finishing. This is why your `sleep 1` fixes it. You could also fix it by making Capybara wait for some new content before `visit report_path`, but then you'd need to write something like a success message to the page (e.g. with the `ajax:success` JS callback).